# NSURLSession tries to access local server over HTTPS

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, nsurlsession

I am developing an ios app that makes request to a server, by making a `POST` request to `example_url`, using `NSURLSession` `dataTaskWithRequest` method.

By mistake during debugging it turned https redirection on on my local server. Of course this doesn't work but my app tried to issue some request at that time.

Now I removed https redirection on my local server settings, but my app still fails when it tries to connect to `example_url`, with the error

```
kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9806
```

On the server side (django) I get something like:

```
ERROR [django.server:basehttp:114] You're accessing the development server over HTTPS, but it only supports HTTP.
```

If I change the url to `example_url_2`, and keep everything else unchanged (redirecting `example_url_2` to the very same function call on the server), things work again.

To me it seems that `NSURLSession` has cached somewhere that it expects this url to be secure, and I would like to know how to reset this.

Comment: can you please add the code which you tried?

Comment: did you add in your info.plist?  <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>

Comment: Yes. Aravind's answer below is the correct one in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Can you just try using

```
NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
configuration.requestCachePolicy = NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData;
```

And use the session object with  `[NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:configuration];`

Use `dataTask` using that `session` object

Comment: Perfect, thanks! It's a bit sad I have to disable the cache for that though. I wonder whether there would be a slightly more fine-grained way to do this ?

Comment: You can use this and once the cache gets cleared you can comment this if needed :)

Comment: Right, but I am more thinking of what if something wrong happens on the production server and user gets errors because of such caching. Also do you know when is the cache actually cleared ? Thinking about it, it sounds like a bug to me that such errors can be caused by stale cache.